# Origin or author of 'Japanese Multiplication Method'

Tags: arithmetic

What is the **origin** or **author** of the method <sup>**1**</sup> shown in the following image?

[image]

---

*Notes*

1. Also known as *Japanese Multiplication Method for Kids*.

Comment: Uhm... Japan...?

Comment: To me it's just a visual expression of the distribution property
$$(10a+b)(10c+d)=100ac+10(bc+ad)+bd.$$
But of course it's a lot more impressive by pictures that way.

Comment: It's much less impressive if you're not dealing with small digits (1, 2, 3, 5) or two-digit numbers.

Comment: Are you asking why it works?

Comment: @GFauxPas I looking for the author of this method.

Answer (score 5):

According to Wikipedia, "It is not known where it arose first, nor whether it developed independently within more than one region of the world".

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_multiplication

Answer (score 0):

This method is just breaking up the numbers into their tens, hundreds, and so on so that you can keep track of place values when multiplying. In this example, 
$$15*23=(10+5)*(20+3)=20*10 + 5*20 + 10*3 + 5*3=200 + 130 + 15$$
So the first digits of each number 1 and 2 correspond to 10 and 20 which when multiply to give the largest place value, the mixed terms are in between and the last digits 5 and 3 give the smallest contribution. So basically, the method is using distributivity and is not very different from other methods. It does nicely keep track of powers of 10.